# git diff displays colors incorrectly

Tags: osx, colors, git, pager

In order to get coloured output from all git commands, I set the following:

```
git config --global color.ui true
```

However, this produces an output like this for `git diff`, `git log`

[image: git diff screenshot]

whereas commands like `git status` display fine

[image: git status screenshot]

Why is it not recognizing the escaped color codes in only some of the commands and how can I fix it?

I'm using iTerm 2 (terminal type `xterm-256color`) on OS X 10.8.2 and zsh as my shell

```
zsh --version
zsh 5.0.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0)

git --version                                                                                                                      
git version 1.7.9.6 (Apple Git-31.1)
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You're seeing the escape sequences that tell the terminal to change colors displayed with the escape character shown as `ESC`, whereas the desired behavior would be that the escape sequences have their intended effect.

Commands such as `git diff` and `git log` pipe their output into a [pager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager), [`less`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29) by default. Git tries to tell `less` to allow control characters to have their control effect, but this isn't working for you.

If `less` is your pager but you have the environment variable `LESS` set to a value that doesn't include `-r` or `-R`, git is unable to tell `less` to display colors. It normally passes `LESS=-FRSX`, but not if `LESS` is already set in the environment. A fix is to explicitly pass the `-R` option to tell `less` to display colors when invoked by git:

```
git config --global core.pager 'less -R'
```

If `less` isn't your pager, either switch to `less` or figure out how to make your pager display colors.

If you don't want git to display colors when it's invoking a pager, set `color.ui` to `auto` instead of `true`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. While I knew that `less` needed `-R` to display colors, I forgot that `git log` and `git diff` piped output to `less`. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't noticed that the default `~/.profile` in FreeBSD had `PAGER=more;     export PAGER`

Comment: Thanks. I had `LESS` set to `-K` because I like being able to `CTRL-C` everything. I thought it was something funky with that variable, and now I know how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

You could also see this output if you have [Busybox](https://busybox.net/). [Alpine Linux](https://alpinelinux.org/) is a good example of a popular distro that uses it. See https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux:FAQ#How_to_enable.2Ffix_colors_for_git.3F

A simple way to know if you currently use Busybox is to run:

```
realpath `which less`
```

Or if you use [fish shell](https://fishshell.com/)

```
realpath (which less)
```

If the output is `/bin/busybox`, then you can solve your problem by installing [gnu less](https://www.gnu.org/software/less/).

On Alpine:

```
sudo apk --update add less
```

The command will be different depending on you distro / package manager.

Comment: Thank you! None of the answers I found online worked for Alpine, finally I found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Improving upon Gilles' [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64932/21808), you can keep your old `$LESS` options by using this in your git config (for example in `~/.gitconfig`):

```
[core]
pager = less -+$LESS -FRX
```

Comment: quazgar's answer is good.  I have `LESS=-i` in my bashrc, So I would have to do

`
[core]pager = less $LESS -FR`

I took out the X, because with X, my existing terminal content gets erased, I prefer that the terminal content stays.